# rabbitMQ - messages count in the rabbitmq panel

Tags: java, rabbitmq

If I get message in the rabbitmq panel, I still see the same number of messages, why? I think it should decrease.

[image]

Comment: How do you get messages from Rabbit?

Comment: Using the button "Get message"

Comment: there was: "requeue yes" - sorry :)